# How do I merge two data frames if a column and it's values exist in both data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I merge two data frames if a column has values in both data frames?

**Data frame 1 – df1**

```
    A   B   C
0   'name1' 'foo'   'bar'
1   'name2' 'foo''  'bar'
2   'name3' 'foo'   NaN
3   'name4' 'foo'   NaN
```

**Data frame 2 – df2**

```
    A   C
0   'name3' 'bar'
1   'name4' 'bar'
```

**I tried this:**

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A')
```

But that does not create the desired output.

**Here is a full minimum example:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv1 = """A,B,C
'name1','foo','bar'
'name2','foo'','bar'
'name3','foo',
'name4','foo',
"""

csv2 = """A,C
'name3','bar'
'name4','bar'
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv1), header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv2), header=0)

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A')
```

**I want this:**

```
    A   B   C
0   'name1' 'foo'   'bar'
1   'name2' 'foo''  'bar'
2   'name3' 'foo'   'bar'
3   'name4' 'foo'   'bar'
```

**But get this:**

```
    A   B   C_x C_y
0   'name1' 'foo'   'bar'   NaN
1   'name2' 'foo''  'bar'   NaN
2   'name3' 'foo'   NaN 'bar'
3   'name4' 'foo'   NaN 'bar'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can do [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) which

> Updates null elements with value in the same location in other.

```
df1.set_index('A').combine_first(df2.set_index('A')).reset_index()
```

---

```
        A       B      C
0  'name1'   'foo'  'bar'
1  'name2'  'foo''  'bar'
2  'name3'   'foo'  'bar'
3  'name4'   'foo'  'bar'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that fast and perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

If the real case data doesn't have the `NaN` on the same location, `combine_first` might fail, in that case you can use `pd.merge` and `Series.fillna`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A', suffixes=['', '_2'])
df['C'].fillna(df['C_2'], inplace=True)
df.drop('C_2', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

```
         A      B      C
0  'name1'  'foo'  'bar'
1  'name2'  'foo'  'bar'
2  'name3'  'foo'  'bar'
3  'name4'  'foo'  'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this if you need to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df3= pd.merge(df, df2, how='left',  on=['A','C'])
print(df3)
```

---

```
         A       B      C
0  'name1'   'foo'  'bar'
1  'name2'  'foo''  'bar'
2  'name3'   'foo'    NaN
3  'name4'   'foo'    NaN
         A      C
0  'name3'  'bar'
1  'name4'  'bar'
         A       B      C
0  'name1'   'foo'  'bar'
1  'name2'  'foo''  'bar'
2  'name3'   'foo'    NaN
3  'name4'   'foo'    NaN
```

Other answers are much better, but definitively you need to use inner join (default for merge), and possible to `ffill` the C column, which would be simple as `df3.C = df3.C.ffill()`